# Hard disk number in boot.ini?

Tags: windows, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which rdisk value in boot.ini maps to which disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/117788/which-rdisk-value-in-boot-ini-maps-to-which-disk)

I need help to remove a confusion. Suppose we have two hard disks.

Referring to boot.ini, In case of MULTI and SCSI syntax: which parameter exactly tells us the hard disk number?

As per my understanding,

- For MULTI syntax:
  rdisk(X) will be used to tell the hard disk number.
- For SCSI syntax:
  disk(X) will be to used as the hard disk number.

Am I right?

Any other thing should I consider?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/117788